# Image position related to table position

Tags: graphics, tabularx, mdframed

How can it be that an image and a table, that are places incide of the same mdframe are positioned differently? And how can it be resolved.

This screen dump shows the problem:
[image]

I would have expected them to both be aligned at the same position (top, center or bottom) and not differently. How do I align them all to the top. So that the text of the tabular begins at the top of the image?

**Update with code example**

I have tried to create an example of how I am getting the "error". I have also found another [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99862/vertically-aligning-text-after-baseline-changed), but I don't know how to apply the answer to my solution as it isn't all the same, but close.

The code example is a little long. However, try to have a look at the method `profileImage` that is used in the beginning og the method `createPerson`, which is the one that positions the image and table inside of an `mdFrame`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref} 


\newsavebox\profileImageBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\profileImage}%
      {O{width=0.6\linewidth}
       O{draw=black,line width=0.75pt,rounded corners=6pt}
       m}{%
   \savebox\profileImageBox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw [path picture={%
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                       \usebox\profileImageBox};},#2]
          (0,0)  rectangle (\wd\profileImageBox,\ht\profileImageBox);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\createPerson{r<>omomo+d<>}
{
    \begin{mdframed}[style=whiteBox]%
        \profileImage[width=0.25\textwidth]{#1}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{lXrc}%
            % Row one
            Navn:   &   \nameref{#3}    & #5    & $\Re$%
            %Create new row if needed
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    {\IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}}%
                        {\\}}%
                    {\\}}%
                {\\}%
            % Row two
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                % If no birth name
                {\IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                    % If no called name
                    {&&}%
                    % If a called name
                    {Kaldenavn: & #2 &}}%
                %If a birth name
                {Fødenavn: & #4 &}%
                %
                \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                       % If no birth date
                       {\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7 & \cross}}%
                       {#6 & $\star$}%
            % Create new row if needed    
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                {%
                \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}%
                        }%
                }%
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    {\IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}%
                        }%
                    }%
                    {\\}%
                }%
            % Row three
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                % If no called name
                {%
                    \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {&&}%
                        }%
                }%
                % If a called name
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    % If no birth name
                    {
                        \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                            {}%
                            {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                                {}%
                                {&&}%
                            }%
                    }%
                    %If birth name
                    {Kaldenavn: & #2 &}%
                }%
            %
            \IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                       % If no death date
                       {}%
                       {\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#7 & \cross}}%
        \end{tabularx}%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][.7pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Edith Marie Larsen}
    \label{EdithMariePetersen1900}


    \createPerson%
        <woman.jpg>%
        [Edith]%
        {EdithMariePetersen1900}%
        [Edith Marie Petersen]%
        {15}%
        [2. okt. 1900]%
        <9. jul. 1970>%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The snippet has been cut and there's no example of usage.

Comment: Boxes are aligned by their respective baselines.  Images have their baseline at the bottom.  Tabulars can select between the bottom (baseline of last line), top (baseline of first line) or center (which may or not be the exact center).  There are numerous examples here on how to adjust the alignment.

Comment: @egreg I have added a real code example now :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think you are right. However, I cant figure out how to apply it in my usecase. I have updated the question with a real example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}[t]{lXrc}
```

for top aligning the tabular and to shift down the picture; an easy way is with `adjustbox`:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
<tikzpicture>
\end{adjustbox}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref} 


\newsavebox\profileImageBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\profileImage}%
      {O{width=0.6\linewidth}
       O{draw=black,line width=0.75pt,rounded corners=6pt}
       m}{%
   \savebox\profileImageBox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
   \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw [path picture={%
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                       \usebox\profileImageBox};},#2]
          (0,0)  rectangle (\wd\profileImageBox,\ht\profileImageBox);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   \end{adjustbox}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\createPerson{r<>omomo+d<>}
{
    \begin{mdframed}[style=whiteBox]%
        \profileImage[width=0.25\textwidth]{#1}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}[t]{lXrc}%
            % Row one
            Navn:   &   \nameref{#3}    & #5    & $\Re$%
            %Create new row if needed
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    {\IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}}%
                        {\\}}%
                    {\\}}%
                {\\}%
            % Row two
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                % If no birth name
                {\IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                    % If no called name
                    {&&}%
                    % If a called name
                    {Kaldenavn: & #2 &}}%
                %If a birth name
                {Fødenavn: & #4 &}%
                %
                \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                       % If no birth date
                       {\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7 & \cross}}%
                       {#6 & $\star$}%
            % Create new row if needed    
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                {%
                \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}%
                        }%
                }%
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    {\IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {\\}%
                        }%
                    }%
                    {\\}%
                }%
            % Row three
            \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                % If no called name
                {%
                    \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                        {}%
                        {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                            {}%
                            {&&}%
                        }%
                }%
                % If a called name
                {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%
                    % If no birth name
                    {
                        \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
                            {}%
                            {\IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                                {}%
                                {&&}%
                            }%
                    }%
                    %If birth name
                    {Kaldenavn: & #2 &}%
                }%
            %
            \IfNoValueTF{#7}%
                       % If no death date
                       {}%
                       {\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#7 & \cross}}%
        \end{tabularx}%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][.7pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Edith Marie Larsen}
    \label{EdithMariePetersen1900}


    \createPerson%
        <../duck.jpg>%
        [Edith]%
        {EdithMariePetersen1900}%
        [Edith Marie Petersen]%
        {15}%
        [2. okt. 1900]%
        <9. jul. 1970>%

\end{document}
```

[image]

A command with seven arguments with various delimiters should certainly be better treated with a single key-value argument.